# Typo3 8.7.x / Extbase: Extend RealUrl in own extension

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, realurl

is it possible to extend realurl configuration in my own extension? I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
//ext_localconf.php of my extension
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']['postVarSets']['_DEFAULT'] = array_merge($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']['postVarSets']['_DEFAULT'],
[
    'gallery' => [
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[gallery]',
            'lookUpTable' => [
                'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_gallery',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'maxLength' => 120,
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'enable404forInvalidAlias' => 1,
                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                'expireDays' => 5,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => [
                    'spaceCharacter' => '_'
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'controller' => [
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[action]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[controller]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[backId]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ],
    ],
]
```

);

If I use the same code at my realurl_conf.php then it's working.

Answer (score 1):

RealURL has an "autoconf" hook for this purpose.

In your `ext_localconf.php` you have to put:

```
if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('realurl')) {
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/realurl/class.tx_realurl_autoconfgen.php']['extensionConfiguration']['my_extkey'] = \Vendor\Ext\Hooks\RealUrlAutoConfiguration::class . '->addConfig';
}
```

your class could look like this:

```
<?php

  namespace Vendor\Ext\Hooks;

  class RealUrlAutoConfiguration
  {

    /**
     * Generates additional RealURL configuration and merges it with provided configuration
     *
     * @param       array $params Default configuration
     *
     * @return      array Updated configuration
     */
    public function addConfig($params)
    {
      return array_merge_recursive($params['config'], [
        'postVarSets' => [
          '_DEFAULT' => [
            'gallery'    => [
              [
                'GETvar'      => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[gallery]',
                'lookUpTable' => [
                  'table'                    => 'tx_myext_domain_model_gallery',
                  'id_field'                 => 'uid',
                  'alias_field'              => 'title',
                  'maxLength'                => 120,
                  'useUniqueCache'           => 1,
                  'addWhereClause'           => ' AND NOT deleted',
                  'enable404forInvalidAlias' => 1,
                  'autoUpdate'               => 1,
                  'expireDays'               => 5,
                  'useUniqueCache_conf'      => [
                    'spaceCharacter' => '_'
                  ]
                ]
              ],
            ],
            'controller' => [
              [
                'GETvar'  => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[action]',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
              ],
              [
                'GETvar'  => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[controller]',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
              ],
              [
                'GETvar'  => 'tx_myext_p1gallery[backId]',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
              ],
            ],
          ]
        ]
      ]);
    }
  }
```

This only works if you have autoconf activated in the RealURL extension configuration (in the Extension manager)

Answer (score 0):

Your modification probably is much to late to be considered by realurl.
Realurl is executed very early in the response process. Probably your extension is not executed until then.

as the realurl_config file is under your control (typical: site extension) and it's only PHP you also can include your extension modification from the 'original' `realurl_conf.php`.

```
if (file_exists('typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Configuration/realurl_additional_conf.php')) {
   include_once('typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Configuration/realurl_additional_conf.php');
}
```

Comment: okay thanks for the advice. I want to get it work without modifying the original realurl conf. At the moment, I'm googling for hooks.

Comment: as mentioned: the very early execution of realurl will make it difficult. my best guess: you might look for a hook in realurl itself.